# Why is grunt-contrib-imagemin not using the option I set?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, compression

I have imagemin working through grunt.

As show below in the Gruntfile, I have things like optimisationLevel: 7 and so on.

The use: command tells it to use a different algo for compressing the images. It listens to all of my options except for the use one.

Anyone know why this is? Am I doing something wrong syntax wise?

Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var mozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     imagemin: {
        dynamic: {                       // Task                        // Target
          options: {
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            progressive: false,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            use: [mozjpeg({fastcrush: true})]
          },
          files: [{
            expand: true,                  // Enable dynamic expansion
            cwd: 'src/',                   // Src matches are relative to this path
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],   // Actual patterns to match
            dest: 'build/img'                  // Destination path prefix
          }]
        }
      }
  });

  // Load the plugins
  //grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  // Default tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);



};
```

[CLI](http://pastebin.com/X0MMbqiU) - You can see on line 40 it says use null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a logging issue of the `grunt.verbose.writeFlags` function which grunt use to [log the task options](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L70) in verbose mode.
If you will add the following code to you gruntfile.js, you will notice it incorrectly logs the value of 'use' as null:

```
grunt.verbose.writeflags({use: [mozjpeg()]}, 'Test');
```

The cause might be this reported [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/884), although it is not exactly the same case.